# Adding extra field with Many to many relationship in DRF

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have scenario where I need to add the  extra field with the ManytoMany relationship. But when I am trying to do so I am getting the error.

My model class is as:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    members = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Membership(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Group')
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

What I am looking here is in a Membership modal I want my code to be unique and in group I want the multiple person with quantity but something I am doing wrong and I am getting the error and my error is :

```
The model is used as an intermediate model by 'oss.Membership.group', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Membership' or 'Person'.
```

Any suggestions will be of great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add extra field with ManytoMany field in DRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169448/add-extra-field-with-manytomany-field-in-drf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have FK relationship towards `Membership` model. Like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    members = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: How I will create rest api for the same. Can you please edit your anser

Comment: I am not getting the group field in admin panel

Comment: you need to share your codes regarding DRF for me to answer on that

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships don't look very logically. You have specified the relationship between `Group` and `Person` to be many to one and the relationship between `Person` and `Membership` to be many to many, going through `Group`. This is very confusing.

Do you rather need a many to many relationship between `Person` and `Group`, going through `Membership`? That means a person can belong (have a membership) to many groups, and a group can have (memberships of) many persons.

If so than you'll have to adjust your models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Group(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')


class Membership(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Probably you'd like to allow a person to have only one membership in a group. If so, you can set a particular field, maybe `code` to be unique. Alternatively you can define `unique_together` in the `Meta` class.